Why do we try to extend the Standard Model with new quantum fields (special relativity) in regions where gravity dominates, like the Big Bang?
The way we define particles nowadays is trough quantum fields. These fields are representations of the Poincaré group (symmetries of the Minkowski space). In this sense, we can only merge strong and electroweak interaction with special relativity, but not GR. Now, one would think that this description of matter is only local (we only consider flat Minkowski instead of the whole Lorentzian manifold in which the particle moves) and it serves us in our experiments good enough. But for cases when the curvature is big, such us big bang, or even galaxies, I wouldn’t trust our definition of fields from the standard model to define particles moving trough a curved spacetime.
Now, as we see, it fails for example in the Big Bang region to predict baryogenesis, which begs for an extension of the SM. Or in the rotation of galaxies, which again calls for dark matter solutions.
Now, I want to know what is the reasoning behind extensions within the SM; extensions that propose new matter fields in the Lagrangian (but always representations of the symmetries of flat space). I don’t really believe new physics will be discovered by adding terms to langrangians, or making them supersymmetric, but before ruling this possibility out, and consider other areas of research, I would like to know the powerful arguments that this community has to offer.
Maybe a subquestion from here. The definition of particle as irreducible reps of the Poincaré group serves us well to some extend. But where does it come from? As I think about it, particles in special relativity move in Minkowski space so they must of course respect the symmetries of it. But more general, they should respect the symmetries of the whole Lorentzian manifold in which they move in right? Or at least their causal submanifold. So I would think that next to big curvatures the own definition of particle is different.
Of course, this is still semiclassical and we need quantum gravity and all that, I get it. Im just a bit confused about all this topic of BSM physics and why proposing new fields like dark matter in order to fix gravitational problems. Or even why using quantum fields in the early universe. Of course intuitive arguments are always welcome, but I would like to see some experimental or well detailed information about this.

Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311740/226902 Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348651/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/563610/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52385/226902

You can already do quantum field theory in curved spacetime; this book, for example, shows how to incorporate cosmological expansion, which creates particles by changing the ladder operators. (Full quantum gravity is more challenging, though.)

Thank you @J.G. , QFT in curved spacetimes is precisely what I was looking for. I have reading a bit and it answers my doubts and intuitions I had
